# Post request in afnetworking 3.0?

Tags: ios, afnetworking, afnetworking-3

I had an application in which I am using `Afnetnetworking3.0` for web service calls like this.

```
AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
[manager setRequestSerializer:[AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer]];
[manager setResponseSerializer:[AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer]];

NSURL * urlStr = [NSURL URLWithString:path];

NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"ID":@"fdfdfd",@"No":@"1414"};
NSLog(@"%@",parameters);

[manager POST:urlStr.absoluteString 
   parameters:parameters 
     progress:nil 
      success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject) {

                                NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);

                            } failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error) {

                                NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
                            }];
```

But it is adding some spaces in parameters dictionary and making the URL not found. Can anybody tell me where I am going wrong ?

Comment: Your code seems fine. There might be something wrong with your url though.

Comment: @NeilGaliaskarov how we will print the final path with parameters

Comment: @hacker firstly, print the path from here `NSURL * urlStr = [NSURL URLWithString:path];` and add the log result to your question

Comment: i already printed the path string,thats same

Answer (score 1):

Try like this :

```
   NSString *Loginurl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://Enter your url here"];


    NSDictionary *params = @{
                             @"ID":@"fdfdfd",
                             @"No":@"1414"
                             };

    NSLog(@"Sent parameter to server 1 : %@",params);
    AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];

    manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializerWithReadingOptions:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments];

    manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];

    AFSecurityPolicy* policy = [AFSecurityPolicy policyWithPinningMode:AFSSLPinningModeCertificate];

    [policy setValidatesDomainName:NO];

    [policy setAllowInvalidCertificates:YES];

    manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObjects:@"application/json", @"text/json", @"text/javascript",@"text/html", nil];

    manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObjects:@"application/json",@"text/html",nil];

    manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObjects:@"application/json",@"text/plain",nil];



    [manager POST:Loginurl parameters:params progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionTask *task, id responseObject) {


        NSLog(@"Response from server 1 :  %@", [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseObject encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);

        [self getdata:responseObject];


    }
          failure:^(NSURLSessionTask *operation, NSError *error)

     {

         NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);

 }];    
}


-(void)getdata:(NSDictionary*)RegisterData
{


}
```

check the log `Sent parameter to server 1`... and check your url is correct or not?